# Link A Single UITableViewCell To Two Different Segues

Tags: ios5, uitableview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, ios

Maybe this is going to sound like a real weird thing I want to do, but let me explain my purpose.

I'm writing an app that links to Dropbox, and it displays the user all his folders and files. I want to write this in such a way that when the user taps a folder, the app will dig in in the folder to display all it's content. But if the user taps a cell that links to a file rather than to a folder, I want to transition to another segue that has a text editor.

I have the dig in logic written up and it works like a charm, but I can't seem to link a single cell to two different segues. Whenever I try to link the segue to my text editor, the previous segue disappears, so I can't link to two segues with the same cell.

What are some alternatives to do this? Naturally, the cells are dynamic. I tried to clone the cell and link to the other segue, but my app would crash because dynamic prototypes can't have more than one cell, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not exactly sure why, but I try adding two cells this time (one will represent folders and another one will represent items) and it didn't crash this time... So now I have two cells that open the respective queues when tapped.